# Issue with the multi index-Please could you correct the issue as the output shows 'Nan'

Tags: pandas, multi-index

```
dts=pd.DataFrame({'x':['1','2','3','4','5','6'],'y':['7','8','9','10','11','12']},index=
                 pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b','c'],['1','2']],names=['Sl','Ok']),columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F'],dtype="float")
dts
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data defined doesn't match your columns constructed in the dataframe.
Remove the 'columns' parameter from your dataframe constructor:

```
dts=pd.DataFrame({'x':['1','2','3','4','5','6'],
                  'y':['7','8','9','10','11','12']},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b','c'],['1','2']],
                  names=['Sl','Ok']),
                  #columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F'], <--- Remove this!
                  dtype="float")
dts
```

Output:

```
         x     y
Sl Ok           
a  1   1.0   7.0
   2   2.0   8.0
b  1   3.0   9.0
   2   4.0  10.0
c  1   5.0  11.0
   2   6.0  12.0
```